# Why is my application's authentication page different to everyone else's?

Tags: facebook

As per the [Authentication Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), I'm directing my user's to the following URL to initiate the authentication flow:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=251747341532139&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

However, instead of the login page looking like:

[image: FB Login]

... (i.e. like it does in the documentation and in other Apps I've created and used), it looks like this...

[image]

Does anyone know why?

I've tracked the redirects that the page makes, and it's as follows:

1. `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=251747341532139&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`
2. `https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=251747341532139&method=permissions.request&display=page&next=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=code&fbconnect=1`
3. `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=251747341532139&skip_api_login=1&display=page&cancel_url=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.&fbconnect=1&next=https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?method=permissions.request&app_id=251747341532139&display=page&redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html&response_type=code&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&rcount=1`

Application type is set to Native/Desktop, and I've set the App Integration to "Website".

If the language I'm using makes any difference, I'm using C#, and setting the `Url` of `System.Windows.Form.WebBrowser`.

Comment: The first screenshot shows a popup, not an entire window. You can display it by setting the `display` parameter to `popup` when calling `FB.login()` in the Facebook JS SDK, but I honestly wouldn't know how to display it with a redirect.

Comment: @MartinodF: Popup or not, the first screenshot is what the Facebook Documentation shows as what should appear when requesting that URL. It's the same dialog that shows for Spotify for one, and they're a Desktop App.

Comment: Just add `&display=popup` at the end of the URL. Was it hard? No. Did I know it beforehand? No. Honestly, you could have just tried.

Comment: @Martin: What's with the cheek? Considering "popup" isn't mentioned once in the whole documentation page for the Authentication System, how was I supposed to guess adding "&display=popup" would be a fix?

Comment: [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) you can find the documentation about the five display types currently available (page, popup, iframe, touch and wap). I told you about the `popup` parameter for the JS SDK because that's what I use, but the SDK just creates the same `/dialog/oauth` URL you wrote by hand with the that params. I didn't say that you were supposed to know that it would have worked, just that it was a matter of reading the docs and trying. Anyway, glad you solved it!

Comment: (BTW, [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) is the documentation about all of the parameters you can use for the oauth dialog. `display` is in there too, but there are some others you could find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the above comments, you can use the `display` parameter in the URL to control which kind of dialog to show, as you would normally do with the JS SDK.

Your URL becomes:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xx&redirect_uri=yy&display=popup
```